# adding and removing a template using ng-show and ng-hide

Tags: html, angularjs

Can I use ng-show and ng-hide to display/hide a html template.
If that template is different html file.
I am trying to split my html file into two parts and show/hide it on a event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `ngShow/ngHide` in conjunction with `ngInclude`:

```
<div ng-show="some_condition">
    <div ng-include="template1_path">
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-show="!some_condition">
    <div ng-include="template2_path">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better is you use ng-if instead ng-show as it would save one html template request.

```
<div ng-if="some_condition">
    <div ng-include="'template1_path.htm'"></div>
</div>

<div ng-if="!some_condition">
    <div ng-include="'template2_path.html'"></div>
</div>
```